# Groovy application-scope variable

Tags: groovy

I'm going to create application-scope document counter. Each user who adds a new document will obtain an unique, incremented number. The question is how it make in groovy. I need variable which is only one instantiated for whole application and is multiaccess proove. Other suggestions are also appreciated.

Comment: Why don't you make it random instead of holding a global value?

Comment: It have to be incremental eg. like invoice numeration.

Comment: So you need to keep this value externally.

Comment: Look into AtomicInteger class of java

Answer (score 0):

Based on the following assumptions:

1. Only one version of class gets loaded in a JVM
2. You got only one application process running
3. You don't need  the counter to be restored when you terminate-restart the application/process. If this is required, look into the TODO: statements

`

```
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;

/**
 * This class contains application context
 */
public class AppContext {

    private static int INIT_VAL = 1;
    static {
        //TODO:may need to have the INIT_VAL restored from file/db if required
    }
    private static final AtomicInteger counter = new AtomicInteger(INIT_VAL);

    /**
     * Gets the current state of counter
     * @return current counter val
     */
    public static int getCounter(){
        return counter.get();
    }

    /**
     * Increments counter by one
     * @return increments and gets the counter value
     */
    public static int incrementCounter(){
        //TODO: may store/update the value to a file/db if counter needs to be preserved after restart
        return counter.incrementAndGet();
    }
}
```

`